# Email Validation with ember.js

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, ember.js

I want to set up validation form in my Ember JS application testing if email exists in the database.

The thing is that I can't call to my store right from `formValidators`.

```
formValidators: {
email: [
  {
    message: 'Please provide email in a valid format',
    validate: (inputValue) => {
      let emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
      return emailPattern.test(inputValue);
    }
  },
  {
    message: 'Email already exist',
    validate: (inputValue, self) => {
      return this.get('store').queryRecord('email',
        {
          filter: {
            email: inputValue
          }
        }).then(function () { return false })
    }
  }
]}
```

When running in chrome console I get this error:

```
 TypeError: _this2.get is not a function(…)
```

I wonder that is quite easy problem, but I spent few hours and have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: Do you realize that the RegExp used in your validator will reject valid addresses, such as `dummy@travelagency.london`?

Answer (score 0):

`_this2` is a variable created by Babel when it transpiled your code.

Babel usually does this with arrow functions so it can simulate their behavior of maintaining the same context as their outer scope.

For example, this code:

```
this.getStuff().then(() => {
  this.getMoreStuff();
});
```

Would transpile to something like:

```
var _then1 = this;
this.getStuff().then(function() {
  _then1.getMoreStuff(); // <-- Use a variable to maintain scope
});
```

This behavior of an arrow function means that, even when used as a method, it would still have `this` pointed to the outer scope of where it was defined.

Example:

```js
var x = {
  m: () => {
    console.log(this === x); // `this` is not x, its global
  }
}

x.m(); // false
```

Try declaring your email validation method as a normal function instead, that should fix your issues:

```
validate: function(inputValue, self) {
  // ...
```

Or even with the method shorthand:

```
validate(inputValue, self) {
  // ...
```

Here's why:

```js
var x = {
  m() {
    console.log(this === x); // `this` is x
  }
}

x.m(); // true
```

Comment: I will write as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i set up an action:

```
validate(inputValue) {
      this.get('store').queryRecord('buyer',
        {
          filter: {
            email: inputValue
          }
        }).then(function (inputValue) {
          console.log(inputValue)
        });
}
```

and in input onChange action:

```
 onChange=(action "validate" validEmail)
```

but there is another error:

```
Assertion Failed: You must include an 'id' for buyer in an object passed to 'push'
```

Comment: When you want to ask additional questions that can't fit in a comment, the appropriate way would be to edit your question, not add another answer :).
As far as your problem goes, the error you have here isn't directly caused by the code you posted. The problem is that your backend is returning result(s) with no id(s). Make sure that the JSON that comes back when you do `store.queryRecord` has an `id` field for each record.